# Wordpress and Joomla Permalinks plus domain redirect to specific subdirectory on Zeus

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, joomla1.5, permalinks, zeus

Here's what I'm trying to do:
joomla in 1 subdirectory, wordpress in another.

mysite.com directs to the joomla directory

mysite.com/blog gives wordpress.

I would also like to use seo friendly permalinks for both.

I am using Zeus Linux shared hosting with Joomla 1.5 and wordpress 2.9.2, and having a great deal of trouble finding a suitable rewrite script. Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick. It is based on the [examples (pdf)](http://support.zeus.com/ZWS_examples.pdf) document, and I haven’t tested it. The Zeus server development has stopped in 2010.

```
match URL into $ with ^blog/*$
if matched then
   set URL = blog/index.php
endif
```

Comment: the OP clearly states he is using Zeus - not Apache. .htaccess is useless, he needs a rewrite.script

Answer (score 0):

You would need something along the lines of the following

```
#Joomla
match URL into $ with (/content/|/component/)              
if matched then set URL = /index.php
#Wordpress
map path into SCRATCH:path from %{URL}  
look for file at %{SCRATCH:path}  
if exists then goto END  
look for dir at %{SCRATCH:path}  
if exists then goto END  
# FIX FOR LOGIN
match URL into $ with ^/blog/wp-.*$  
if matched then goto END  
# FIX FOR SEARCH
match URL into $ with ^/blog/(.*)  
set URL = /blog/index.php/$1
```